# Check if two lists are equal

Tags: c#, linq

I have a class as follows:

```
public class Tag {
    public Int32 Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I have two lists of tag:

```
List<Tag> tags1;
List<Tag> tags2;
```

I used [LINQ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Language_Integrated_Query)'s select to get the Ids of each tags list. And then:

```
List<Int32> ids1 = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<Int32> ids2 = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
List<Int32> ids3 = new List<Int32> { 2, 1, 3, 4 };
List<Int32> ids4 = new List<Int32> { 1, 2, 3, 5 };
List<Int32> ids5 = new List<Int32> { 1, 1, 3, 4 };
```

ids1 should be equal to ids2 and ids3 ... Both have the same numbers.

ids1 should not be equal to ids4 and to ids5 ...

I tried the following:

```
var a = ints1.Equals(ints2);
var b = ints1.Equals(ints3);
```

But both give me false.

What is the fastest way to check if the lists of tags are equal?

**UPDATE**

I am looking for POSTS which TAGS are exactly the same as the TAGS in a BOOK.

```
IRepository repository = new Repository(new Context());

IList<Tags> tags = new List<Tag> { new Tag { Id = 1 }, new Tag { Id = 2 } };

Book book = new Book { Tags = new List<Tag> { new Tag { Id = 1 }, new Tag { Id = 2 } } };

var posts = repository
  .Include<Post>(x => x.Tags)
  .Where(x => new HashSet<Int32>(tags.Select(y => y.Id)).SetEquals(book.Tags.Select(y => y.Id)))
  .ToList();
```

I am using [Entity Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET_Entity_Framework) and I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean SetEquals(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Int32])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

How do I solve this?

Comment: What do you mean by not equality exacly, do you mean all elements should be different or just they shouldn't contains same elements,at least there should be one different?

Comment: Your sequence `ids5` contains duplicates. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Selman22 I mean that the two lists should contain exactly the same elements ... The order does not matter

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, it does not make since since in this case IDs are unique because they are primary keys.

Comment: You may want to post the updated question separately, because after the edit the question will have an entirely different solution from anything that has been posted so far. Add `[EF]` tag, and make sure that the title of the new question says "comparing lists inside EF's Where clause" or something similar.

Comment: The answers here are fairly different than the marked duplicate, because this specifically deals with lists of value types, as opposed to the other question that is a list of reference types.  The answers to the linked question are significantly more complicated due to dealing with the reference types.  Nominating to reopen

Comment: I agree with @AaronLS except that to me the main problem of the dup target is that it's trying to deal with lists with the same elements but not necessarily in the same order.  This question is simpler and the answer should reflect that.  Hence I've re-opened this question.

Comment: @MiguelMoura, Just for your information: do you know the accepted answer don't work for {2,2,3} and {2,3,3}. I mean, it does not fit your requirements for duplicates. I made some tests and added a benchmark with few more algorithms as an answer for you to verify what I say. Perhaps you should select another answer? ;-)

Answer (score 530, accepted):

Use [`SequenceEqual`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to check for sequence equality because `Equals` method checks for *reference equality*.

```
var a = ints1.SequenceEqual(ints2);
```

Or if you don't care about elements order use [`Enumerable.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
var a = ints1.All(ints2.Contains);
```

The second version also requires another check for `Count` because it would return true even if `ints2` contains more elements than `ints1`. So the more correct version would be something like this:

```
var a = ints1.All(ints2.Contains) && ints1.Count == ints2.Count;
```

In order to check *inequality* just reverse the result of `All` method:

```
var a = !ints1.All(ints2.Contains)
```

Comment: Maybe using Except and Interect would be a better option? I am not sure if your solution is fast when integrated in a Linq to Entities query since I I need to select all the IDS multiple times ... Or maybe I am wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure.You need to try both and look at the generated sql.BTW did you try this solution ? did you get `NotSupportedException`  or did it converted succesfully?

Comment: Slow and doesn't handle duplicates. `[1, 1, 2] != [1, 2, 2]`

Comment: @CodesInChaos according to OP's comment in the question duplicates doesn't matter

Comment: Note: You might be used to using `.All` with a lambda like `.All(i=> ints2.Contains(i))`, but since list.Contains() matches the function signature of taking a `int` and returning a `bool`, then he is passing the function name directly as a predicate.  Essentially the same as `ints1.All(i=> ints2.Contains(i))`.  Just wanted to point this out in case others like me were initially confused.

Comment: Almost committed a bug since I implemented your second example not reading further and seeing a Count check was needed (third example). :)

Comment: I would revert the order of the `var a = ints1.All(ints2.Contains) && ints1.Count == ints2.Count;` to `var a = ints1.Count == ints2.Count && ints1.All(ints2.Contains);`. A simple count comparison is likely much faster than the `.All` call. If counts are not equal it would return faster.

Comment: I will downvote this answer because this does not apply for all cases, List A {a,a} and list B contains {b,a} now ListB.All(listA.contains) and LIstA.All(listB.contains) will give different results, since both have same count, we will get true in one of them even though both are different, it wont work if a list has multiple entries –

Comment: `var a = ints1.All(ints2.Contains) && ints1.Count == ints2.Count;` Let's hope that `ints1` isn't `{1,1,2}` when `ints2` is `{1,2,3}`. Since this answer will say they are equivalent.

Comment: Why am I getting an error about ints2.Contains?

Comment: @AaronLS, You mentioned above that you don't need to create a complete lambda with a parameter list passed in for the 'ints1.All(ints2.Contains)'.  How far does concept go in the .Net ecosystem?  Is it just for any predicate within a LINQ query, or is it seen elsewhere in .Net?

Comment: All(Contains) is O(N^2), you can do better by sorting.

Comment: Couldn't you combine the GetHashCode() of all elements for both lists, then compare the two resulting hash codes? Is there a method that already exists that does this?

Comment: You are assuming that .SequenceEqual does not check for reference equality but microsoft docs says different. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-3.1

If you want to compare the actual data of the objects in the sequences instead of just comparing their references, you have to implement the IEqualityComparer<T> generic interface in your class.

Comment: I think this one does work with duplicates: `var listsAreEqual = list1.Count == list2.Count && list1.All(a => list2.Count(i => i.Name == a.Name) == list1.Count(i => i.Name == a.Name));` It will iterate over all elements and check if both list contains the equal amount of them. Of course this could still be improved performance wise but that is not the clue of my comment.

Answer (score 158):

`List<T>` equality does not check them element-by-element. You can use [LINQ's `SequenceEqual` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348567%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that:

```
var a = ints1.SequenceEqual(ints2);
```

To ignore order, use `SetEquals`:

```
var a = new HashSet<int>(ints1).SetEquals(ints2);
```

This should work, because you are comparing sequences of IDs, which do not contain duplicates. If it does, and you need to take duplicates into account, the way to do it in linear time is to compose a hash-based dictionary of counts, add one for each element of the first sequence, subtract one for each element of the second sequence, and check if the resultant counts are all zeros:

```
var counts = ints1
    .GroupBy(v => v)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
var ok = true;
foreach (var n in ints2) {
    int c;
    if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out c)) {
        counts[n] = c-1;
    } else {
        ok = false;
        break;
    }
}
var res = ok && counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
```

Finally, if you are fine with an `O(N*LogN)` solution, you can sort the two sequences, and compare them for equality using `SequenceEqual`.

Comment: With `SequenceEqual` the elements must be in the same order - OP wants the same elements in _any_ order.

Comment: @DStanley You're right, I missed this initially. Should be fine now.

Comment: Before the edit your answer was wrong because OP wants to ignore the order, now `SetEquals` does not take duplicates into account (OP wasn't clear).

Comment: @TimSchmelter That's what editing is for. How's it looking *after* the edit?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight still will not work if either sequence contains duplcates - `{1, 1, 2, 3}` would be "equal" to `{1, 2, 2, 3}`

Comment: @DStanley A sequence of `Id`s cannot possibly contain duplicates.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: maybe something like this would work: `bool isEqual = ids1.Count == ids2.Count; if (isEqual) isEqual = ids1.OrderBy(i=>i).SequenceEqual(ids2.OrderBy(i => i));`.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Sure it can.  In fact the fifth sequence in the OP's exmaple _does_.

Comment: @DStanley I just asked him a question about it.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I just updated my example ... I am also looking for a solution that can be used in a Linq to Entities query ...

Comment: @MDMoura I see - so it's not just that you need to compare the two lists, but you also need them to be compared in the database, because the condition is part of the `Where` clause in EF? It's a more interesting question, I'd have to think of how to do it.

Comment: Yes, basically a book contains a group of tags ... So given a book I need to get all posts which has exactly the same tags as that book. Of course order does not matter ...

Comment: @SergeyKalinichenko, Hi, thanks for your answer. Your answer sounds wonderful but I think you under estimate some functions of LINQ. I'm not sure which one exactly, I though it was the grouping but my tests showed me it was the ToDictionary (but it defpends if it use yield or not). Anyway, I post an answer showing speed AND you will be pretty surprised of the result I think. PLEASE keep your code as is. If you want to modify it, can you add another answer instead of modifying your code. Thanks. You can see speed and code in my answer ;-) !!!

Answer (score 30):

```
Enumerable.SequenceEqual(FirstList.OrderBy(fElement => fElement), 
                         SecondList.OrderBy(sElement => sElement))
```

Comment: The name of your lambda parameter is weird. They're no list, they're an element. I'd either go with `id` in the OP's context, or `element` in a generic context.

Comment: This guy clearly copied this answer from elsewhere since judging by the parameter names he doesn't even know what it does..

Comment: I think it covers exactly the issue at hand. It compares two lists, no matter the sequence.

Comment: You can even add `.Distinct()` before the `OrderBy`s if you want to compare and ignore duplicates. This is definitely not the most efficient method of comparing sets. HashSet.SetEquals ignores duplicates and order. Enumerable.SequenceEquals considers duplicates and preserves order.

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer for almost 10 years now (Selman answer) is not working for duplicate (in question we can see duplicates). You can try yourself with: {2, 2, 3} and {2, 3, 3} where Selman algo say equal. I agree its not obvious at first sight.

The second most voted up answer (Sergey) include comments that suggest a very fast algorithm. I made a little benchmark (code at the bottom). I included 3 answers (Selman, Sergey, Pankaj). I also added 2 new algorithms (Guru and EricO). According to my benchmark, Sergey algorithm is not very fast compare to some others. I know speed was not a criteria of the question itself, but author answer suggest a very efficient algorithm.

Included here, a little benchmark to compare proposed solutions plus 2 more. Far from being perfect and complete, the benchmark could give a good idea of validity and performance. I suggest that you check results before choosing what you want to implement in your own code.

Test code and compare functions implementations are below results. Thanks to Guru for its feedback and good idea on an algorithm (I think it worth to be an answer of its own ;-)).

Results:

```
Start Compare for Int32 of size: 3
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman    : 00:00:00.0006856. Equal: True  <<<<< ERROR
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.0045392. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.0019844. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.0002651. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.0005945. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 10000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:11.6260563. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:03.2376179. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:01.0078811. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:01.5709527. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 10000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:12.9824722. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:03.8619141. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:01.0829506. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:02.0760940. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 10000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:16.3923001. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:54.0820172. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:53.5317528. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:05.9972781. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 10000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:14.3085444. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:54.4835349. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:53.6763668. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:05.6920709. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 1000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.7707951. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.2131278. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.0892336. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.5455456. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 1000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.5982986. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.2248797. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.0937744. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.1462340. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 1000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:01.3971059. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:04.3682767. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:03.7275648. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.4822032. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 1000000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:01.1479243. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:04.2601652. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:03.7690159. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.2350588. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 100000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.1446754. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.0212269. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.0087268. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.0081945. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for Int32 of size: 100000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.0245328. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.0232001. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.0075184. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.0139519. Equal: False
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 100000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.0808056. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.2401923. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.1936675. Equal: True
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.0392954. Equal: True
End Compare

Start Compare for String of size: 100000
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey    : 00:00:00.1257959. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj    : 00:00:00.2398588. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru      : 00:00:00.2811503. Equal: False
CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO     : 00:00:00.0406129. Equal: False
End Compare
```

Test Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Text;
using General.Compare;

namespace ConsoleAppTestEnumCompare
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Show error in accepted solution of SO question
            int[] itemsToShowStackOverflowAcceptedAnswerError = new int[] { 2, 2, 3 };
            int[] itemsToShowStackOverflowAcceptedAnswerError2 = new int[] { 2, 3, 3 };
            Test(itemsToShowStackOverflowAcceptedAnswerError, itemsToShowStackOverflowAcceptedAnswerError2);

            // Major tests for int and string
            foreach (var countOfInt in new int[] { 100000000, 10000000, 1000000, 100000 })
            {
                Random rnd = new Random();
                List<int> list1 = new List<int>();
                for (int i = 0; i < countOfInt; i++)
                {
                    list1.Add(rnd.Next(list1.Count));
                }
                List<int> list2 = new List<int>(list1);
                list2.Sort();

                Test(list1, list2);

                list1[list1.Count / 2] = list1[list1.Count / 2] + 1;

                Test(list1, list2);

                List<string> listString1 = new List<string>();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < countOfInt; i++)
                {
                    sb.Clear();
                    int stringSize = rnd.Next(1, 12);
                    for (int n = 0; n < stringSize; n++)
                    {
                        sb.Append((char)rnd.Next((int)'a', (int)'z'));
                    }

                    listString1.Add(sb.ToString());
                }
                List<string> listString2 = new List<string>(listString1);
                listString2.Sort();

                Test(listString1, listString2);

                listString1[listString1.Count / 2] = listString1[listString1.Count / 2] + 1;

                Test(listString1, listString2);
            }
        }

        static void Test<T>(IEnumerable<T> list1, IEnumerable<T> list2)
        {
            (Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, bool> Compare, string Name)[] compareActions = new (Func<IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable<T>, bool>, string)[5];
            compareActions[0] = (CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman, nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman));
            compareActions[1] = (CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey, nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey));
            compareActions[2] = (CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj, nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj));
            compareActions[3] = (CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru, nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru));
            compareActions[4] = (CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO, nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO));

            Debug.WriteLine($"Start Compare for {typeof(T).Name} of size: {list1.Count()}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Start Compare for {typeof(T).Name} of size: {list1.Count()}");

            bool areListsEqual;
            Stopwatch stopwatch;
             
            foreach(var compareAction in compareActions)
            {
                if (list1.Count() > 100 && compareAction.Name == nameof(CompareEnumerableExtension.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman)) 
                {
                    continue; // Too slow and does not work
                }

                stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                areListsEqual = compareAction.Compare(list1, list2);
                stopwatch.Stop();
                Debug.WriteLine($"{compareAction.Name, -33}  : {stopwatch.Elapsed}. Equal: {areListsEqual}");
                Console.WriteLine($"{compareAction.Name, -33}  : {stopwatch.Elapsed}. Equal: {areListsEqual}");
            }

            Debug.WriteLine("End Compare");
            Console.WriteLine("End Compare");

            Debug.WriteLine("");
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Compare functions:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace General.Compare
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Based on question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal
    /// </summary>
    public static class CompareEnumerableExtension
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality where items should be in the same order
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableInSameOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        {
            return enum1.SequenceEqual(enum2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality in ANY order (SLOW).
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        {
            return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(enum1.OrderBy(fElement => fElement), enum2.OrderBy(sElement => sElement));
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality in ANY order (VERY SLOW). In reality, it just does not work with duplicate.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2) 
        {
            return enum1.Count() == enum2.Count() && enum1.All(enum2.Contains);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality in ANY order. Supposed to be Fast (according to Author in SO) but very slow.
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        {
            var counts = enum1.GroupBy(v => v).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
            var ok = true;
            foreach (var n in enum2)
            {
                if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
                {
                    counts[n] = c - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ok && counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality in ANY order (ORDER DESTRUCTIVE on LIST). Just for fun.
        /// Code based on suggestion from "Guru Stron" on comments of my first answer
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        {
            var list1 = new List<T>(enum1);
            list1.Sort();

            var list2 = new List<T>(enum2);
            list2.Sort();

            return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check for Equality in ANY order (Fast). Support null
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
        /// <param name="enum1"></param>
        /// <param name="enum2"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        {
            if (enum1.Count() != enum2.Count())
                return false;

            // null value is never insert in the map, they are calculated outside of it.
#pragma warning disable CS8714 // The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method. Nullability of type argument doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.
            Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>(enum1.Count());
#pragma warning restore CS8714 // The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method. Nullability of type argument doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.

            int nullCount = 0;

            foreach (var n in enum1)
            {
                if (n == null)
                {
                    nullCount++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
                {
                    counts[n] = c + 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    counts[n] = 1;
                }
            }

            var ok = true;
            foreach (var n in enum2)
            {
                if (n == null)
                {
                    nullCount++;
                    continue;
                }

                if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
                {
                    counts[n] = c - 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    ok = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return ok && nullCount == 0 && counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use [BenchmarkDotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to do performance analysis.

Comment: @GuruStron, are you the one who downvote and if yes, why??? It just show a tendency which is by the order of the near double speed.  I don't see why that would require a Benchmark? The difference is so huge that I can't see why It would need anything else than a quick look to see what's better. What a benchmark would brings more?

Comment: 1) No, it wasn't me who downvoted 2) I can find several reasons why - a) your test is not a proper benchmarking b) your test makes some assumptions about data - for example for data with low number of unique integers but with high number of duplicates it can perform worse than original c) your test assumes working with materialized collections which is not always the case (though question specifies lists) 3) _"I don't see why that would require a Benchmark? "_ - because arguing about performance requires using right tools. `Stopwatch` as is is  not one of them.

Comment: P.S. I agree that creating a collection of right size from the get go is usually a good way to handle things.

Comment: You are right on some points, like duplicates amount or simply the data type (where it was 'int' in the question but could be really different in reality). I think that Stopwatch is OK (not perfect but sufficient in this case). The worse problem I see in my test is the usage of debug mode which could lead to pretty biased behaviors. I will try in release and perhaprs your tool. But I already lost a lot of time just doing this and publishing it for the community just as pure information only. I was only based on some programmer instinct that Sergey code wasn't that fast and had some  slowness

Comment: There are also other things which such test can miss - JIT warmup and initial assembly loading and method compilation - so order can affect the output for first tests. Also personally I would look into testing `ToLookup` instead of `GroupBy` + `ToDictionary` (should not greatly affect the comparisons with your approach though due to collection resizing being the differentiating factor, I guess).

Comment: Also I suggest trying `List<T>.Sort` in addition to `OrderBy` approach (when preserving original order is not needed in-place sorting can save quite some time compared to LINQ).

Comment: @GuruStron, Very good point, I will dot it!!!

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75942441/2501279). Though again it should not beat the counting approach due to the complexity (`O(n)` vs `O(n log n)` if I'm correct - it's a bit late for me =) )

Comment: It could be good for fun to know the difference in performance (list.sort usage) but it destroy the intial enum which is not really a good idea in many cases... OOPS, I just saw that yo make a copy before...

Comment: @GuruStron, sorting is place give a huge boost to the most regarded solution. But it has the drawback to be order destructive if keeping the order is a requirement. Otherwise it apppears to be a great way to do it !!!

Comment: @GuruStron, You are 100% right, my tests were biased and still they are. But I added string just to give a better overview. One another reason was that you were faster than me on "int" ;-) !!! Thanks for your advise. I'm too lazy for using BEnchmarkDotNet but thank you very much for let me know. I'm really happy to know the existence of that tool. 

Comment: Just a small nitpick - _"The accepted answer for almost 10 years now is just not working."_ - it still works (or it was never working depending on point of view) - the answer clearly does not take duplicates into account and it can be a valid case (especially that OP does not have duplicates except for `id5` which can be a typo)

Comment: @GuruStron, Good point!!! The fact that he inserted 2 identicals items in its array is clearly (to me) because he want to ensure full equality but I can be wrong, I should agree. I wonder what will be the reaction of peoples. I think most peoples would expect the same as I did but I can be wrong. For me there is only 2 possibilities (exact equality in value AND exact equality in value and position).

Answer (score -1):

I did the benchmark of @eric-ouellet post, including my version (kinda same of eric's solution with a little refactoring + early loop break).

*I don't fully understand how BenchMarkDotNet work behind the scene, and can't really get it why there is so much difference from means of methods to other ones.*

**EDIT** (brief explanation) :

I did my benchmark against 100 random pairs of `int[10]` and 100 random pairs of `string[10]` arrays.

They have a probability that each of the 2 second generated ones are either simply the first one shuffled, or a new random one with a recursing probability of corrupted (a random item value set to `default`) datas to handle several scenarii.

*Not used in my benchmark, but it could also generate a random array's length centered of the expected length.*

```
/// The class that will be the entry point of my benchmarks
public class EnumerableComparison
{
    /// Set the size and length of my randomly generated enumerable to benchmark.
    private const int _batchSize = 100;
    private const int _batchLength = 10;

    /// Calling our (static) algorithms from this (benchmark) class.
    /// Decorate each call with [Benchmark] attribute to tell
    /// BenchmarkDotNet to benchmark this method.
    /// Also with [ArgumentsSource(Rnd***Datas)] to tell
    /// BenchMarkDotNet to provide our benchmarked methods with
    /// arguments generated with the Rnd***Datas() method.

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool OnlyOrdered_Duplicate(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableInSameOrder<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool OnlyOrdered_Duplicate(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableInSameOrder<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableInSameOrder<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableInSameOrder(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Pankaj(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Pankaj(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_NoDuplicate_Selman(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_NoDuplicate_Selman(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Sergey(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Sergey(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Guru(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_Guru(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_EricO(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_EricO(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO(second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndIntDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_TRex(int[] first, int[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderTRexAll<int>(first, second);

    [Benchmark]
    [ArgumentsSource(nameof(RndStringDatas))]
    public bool AnyOrder_Duplicate_TRex(string[] first, string[] second)
        => CompareEnumerableAnyOrderTRexAll<string>(first, second);

    public bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderTRexAll<T>(IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
        => first.EnumerableEqualsAllV3(second);    

    /// <summary>
    /// Generate a pair of <typeparamref name="T"/>[] having a centered length
    /// of <paramref name="batchLength"/>, that could be randomly altered 
    /// according to <paramref name="lengthVariation"/> value.
    /// The first one is using <paramref name="selector"/> delegate
    /// to generate the <typeparamref name="T"/> items
    /// and second one is either the first one shuffled according to 
    /// <paramref name="copyProbability"/> value,
    /// or a new generated one using <paramref name="selector"/> delegate again
    /// Both have a <paramref name="duplicationProbability"/>
    /// recursing probability to duplicate a random generated element
    /// and a <paramref name="corruptProbability"/>
    /// recursing probability to corrupt a random generated element.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">
    /// The type of generated pairs of <typeparamref name="T"/>[]
    /// </typeparam>
    /// <param name="batchSize">
    /// The number of generated pairs of <typeparamref name="T"/>[]
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="batchLength">
    /// The length of generated pairs of <typeparamref name="T"/>[]
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="selector">
    /// The delegate to transform the index of generated 
    /// <see cref="IEnumerable{int}"/> into an <typeparamref name="T"/>[]
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="corruptProbability">
    /// The probability to corrupt (set to default(<typeparamref name="T"/>))"/>
    /// a random element of the generated pairs
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="copyProbability">
    /// The probability that the second element of the generated pair is simply
    /// the first element of the pair shuffled.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="duplicationProbability">
    /// The recursive probability that a random element of 
    /// a generated <typeparamref name="T"/>[] is duplicated.
    /// </param>
    /// <param name="lengthVariation">
    /// The percentage amount to randomly modify <paramref name="batchLength"/>
    /// </param>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="IEnumerable{object}"/> whose all item are a generated pair
    /// of <typeparamref name="T"/>[]
    /// </returns>

    public IEnumerable<object[]> RandomizedDatas<T>(
        int batchSize, 
        int batchLength, 
        Func<int, T> selector, 
        int corruptProbability = 5, 
        int copyProbability = 20, 
        int duplicationProbability = 50, 
        double lengthVariation = 0.0)
    {
        batchLength = Math.Abs(batchLength);
        lengthVariation = Math.Clamp(lengthVariation, 0.0, 1.0);
        copyProbability = Math.Clamp(copyProbability, 0, 100);
        corruptProbability = Math.Clamp(corruptProbability, 0, 99);
        duplicationProbability = Math.Clamp(duplicationProbability, 0, 99);
        
        T[]? sample1, sample2;
        for (int i = 0; i < batchSize; i++)
        {
            sample1 = Enumerable.Range(1, Math.Max(1, Helper.StaticRandom.Next((int)Math.Floor(batchLength * (1.0 - lengthVariation)), (int)Math.Ceiling(batchLength * (1.0 + lengthVariation)))))
            .Select(selector).ToArray();

                while (Helper.StaticRandom.Next(0, 101) < duplicationProbability)
                    sample1 = sample1.AddRandomDuplicate();

            while (Helper.StaticRandom.Next(0, 101) < corruptProbability)
                sample1 = sample1.Corrupt();

            if (Helper.StaticRandom.Next(0, 101) < copyProbability)
                sample2 = sample1.CopyShuffle();
            else
            {
                sample2 = Enumerable.Range(1, Math.Max(1, Helper.StaticRandom.Next((int)Math.Floor(batchLength * (1.0 - lengthVariation)), (int)Math.Ceiling(batchLength * (1.0 + lengthVariation)))))
                .Select(selector).ToArray();

                while (Helper.StaticRandom.Next(0, 101) < duplicationProbability)
                    sample2 = sample2.AddRandomDuplicate();

                while (Helper.StaticRandom.Next(0, 101) < corruptProbability)
                    sample2 = sample2.Corrupt();
            }

            yield return new object[] { sample1, sample2 };
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<object[]> RndIntDatas()
        => RandomizedDatas(_batchSize, _batchLength, _ => Helper.StaticRandom.Next(1, _batchLength*10));
    
    public IEnumerable<object[]> RndStringDatas()
        => RandomizedDatas(_batchSize, _batchLength, _ => Helper.RandomString(Helper.StaticRandom.Next(1, _batchLength)));  
}
```

And

```
public static class Helper
{
    private static Random _staticRandom = new();
    public static Random StaticRandom => _staticRandom;

    private const string ALPHANUMERICAL = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    public static string RandomString(int lenght)
    {
        var stringChars = new char[lenght];

        for (int i = 0; i < stringChars.Length; i++)
        {
            stringChars[i] = ALPHANUMERICAL[_staticRandom.Next(ALPHANUMERICAL.Length)];
        }

        return new string(stringChars);
    }

    public static T[] CopyShuffle<T>(this T[] values)
    {
        T[] shuffled = new T[values.Length];
        values.CopyTo(shuffled, 0);

        Random.Shared.Shuffle(shuffled);

        return shuffled;
    }

    public static T[] Corrupt<T>(this T[] values)
    {
        values[StaticRandom.Next(0, values.Length)] = default;
        return values;
    }

    public static T[] AddDuplicate<T>(this T[] values, int index)
    {
        if (values == null || index >= values.Length)
            return values;

        return values.Concat(new T[] { values[index] }).ToArray();
    }

    public static T[] AddRandomDuplicate<T>(this T[] values)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length == 0)
            return values;

        return values.AddDuplicate(StaticRandom.Next(0, values.Length));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality where items should be in the same order
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableInSameOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        => enum1.SequenceEqual(enum2);

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality in ANY order (SLOW).
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderPankaj<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        => Enumerable.SequenceEqual(enum1.OrderBy(fElement => fElement), enum2.OrderBy(sElement => sElement));

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality in ANY order (VERY SLOW). In reality, it just does not work with duplicate.
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSelman<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
        => enum1.Count() == enum2.Count() && enum1.All(enum2.Contains);

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality in ANY order. Supposed to be Fast (according to Author in SO) but very slow.
    /// Error on NULL element !
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderSergey<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
    {
        var counts = enum1.GroupBy(v => v).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
        var ok = true;
        foreach (var n in enum2)
        {
            if (n == null)///ADDED to avoid crash
                return false;

            if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
            {
                counts[n] = c - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ok && counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality in ANY order (ORDER DESTRUCTIVE on LIST). Just for fun.
    /// Code based on suggestion from "Guru Stron" on comments of my first answer
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns>return true if both are equals</returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderGuru<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
    {
        var list1 = new List<T>(enum1);
        list1.Sort();

        var list2 = new List<T>(enum2);
        list2.Sort();

        return Enumerable.SequenceEqual(list1, list2);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for Equality in ANY order (Fast). Support null
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T"></typeparam>
    /// <param name="enum1"></param>
    /// <param name="enum2"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool CompareEnumerableAnyOrderEricO<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enum1, IEnumerable<T> enum2)
    {
        if (enum1.Count() != enum2.Count())
            return false;

        // null value is never insert in the map, they are calculated outside of it.
#pragma warning disable CS8714 // The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method. Nullability of type argument doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.
        Dictionary<T, int> counts = new Dictionary<T, int>(enum1.Count());
#pragma warning restore CS8714 // The type cannot be used as type parameter in the generic type or method. Nullability of type argument doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.

        int nullCount = 0;

        foreach (var n in enum1)
        {
            if (n == null)
            {
                nullCount++;
                continue;
            }

            if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
            {
                counts[n] = c + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                counts[n] = 1;
            }
        }

        var ok = true;
        foreach (var n in enum2)
        {
            if (n == null)
            {
                nullCount++;
                continue;
            }

            if (counts.TryGetValue(n, out int c))
            {
                counts[n] = c - 1;
            }
            else
            {
                ok = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return ok && nullCount == 0 && counts.Values.All(c => c == 0);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Check for equality in Any order. Handle duplicate 
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type of elements in <paramref name="first"/> and <paramref name="second"/> <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to test equality </typeparam>
    /// <param name="first">The first <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to test equality against <paramref name="second"/></param>
    /// <param name="second">The second <see cref="IEnumerable{T}"/> to test equality against <paramref name="first"/></param>
    /// <returns>True if <paramref name="first"/> exactly have same elements than those in <paramref name="second"/> without taking order in consideration (duplicate are important)</returns>
    public static bool EnumerableEqualsAllV3<T>(this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second)
    {
        if (first == default && second == default)
            return true;

        if (first == default || second == default)
            return false;

        if (ReferenceEquals(first, second))
            return true;

        int firstCount = first.Count();

        if (firstCount != second.Count())
            return false;

        IDictionary<T, int> mappedCount = new Dictionary<T, int>(firstCount);

        int nullCount = 0;            

        foreach (T item in first)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                nullCount++;
                continue;
            }

            if (mappedCount.ContainsKey(item))
            {
                mappedCount[item]++;
            }
            else
            {
                mappedCount[item] = 1;
            }
        }

        foreach (T item in second)
        {
            if (item == null)
            {
                nullCount--;
                continue;
            }

            if (!mappedCount.ContainsKey(item))
                return false;

            mappedCount[item]--;
        }

        return mappedCount.Values.All(count => count == 0);
    }
}
```

Here are (*pre edited*) [the results](https://pastebin.com/9bMwFS65). (too long to be post in this post unfortunately, so is the use of pastebin site).

Comment: It's not very useful to add this long listing of bare results, esp. not in an external link that is inevitably going to break one day. *Aggregate* these results and discuss the conclusions.

Comment: I slightly modified the code so Ill run another benchmark, but it take time (8h +/-). To aggregate I searched an option in BenchmarkDotNet, but couldn't find one that will merge all result of same method across my 2 * 100 random testing sample. Could do it aside with the generated log.