# EqualityComparer on a nested object

Tags: c#

I would like to compare two list of nested objects. If the parent objects `Id` differ and/or any of the childrens `Id` or `Baz` property differs, I want to consider them changed.

I've implemented my own version of `Equals` and `GetHashCode` below, but despite using my own equalitycomparer, `Except()` still yields a result, while I expect the objects to be equal.

```
var foo1 = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Bars = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar
        {
            Id = 1,
            Baz = 1.5
        },
        new Bar
        {
            Id = 1,
            Baz = 1.5
        }
    }
};

var foo2 = new Foo
{
    Id = 1,
    Bars = new List<Bar>
    {
        new Bar
        {
            Id = 1,
            Baz = 1.5
        },
        new Bar
        {
            Id = 1,
            Baz = 1.5
        }
    }
};

var diff = new[] { foo1 }.Except(new[] { foo2 });
```

```
public class Foo
{
    private sealed class IdBarsEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Foo>
    {
        public bool Equals(Foo x, Foo y)
        {
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (ReferenceEquals(x, null)) return false;
            if (ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;
            if (x.GetType() != y.GetType()) return false;
            return x.Id == y.Id && Equals(x.Bars, y.Bars);
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Foo obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                return (obj.Id * 397) ^ (obj.Bars != null ? obj.Bars.GetHashCode() : 0);
            }
        }
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<Foo> IdBarsComparer { get; } = new IdBarsEqualityComparer();

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

public class Bar
{
    protected bool Equals(Bar other)
    {
        return Id == other.Id && Baz.Equals(other.Baz);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (ReferenceEquals(this, obj)) return true;
        if (obj.GetType() != this.GetType()) return false;
        return Equals((Bar) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            return (Id * 397) ^ Baz.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public double Baz { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are three things wrong in your code:

1. You are not passing the equality comparer to `Except` method, so it's not being used.
2. Your `GetHashCode` implementation in `Foo` is wrong, it returns different results for same objects, so the `Equals` method is never called.
3. You are calling equals on two lists: `Equals(x.Bars, y.Bars)`, this checks for reference equality. You can use `SequenceEqual` instead to compare elements one by one: `x.Bars.SequenceEqual(y.Bars)`

Comment: Thanks, 1. was a typo in the sample code. Can you give an example on what 2. should look like? Regarding 3. would `x.Bars.All(y.Bars.Contains)` work too?

Comment: @filur for 2. : have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094867/good-gethashcode-override-for-list-of-foo-objects-respecting-the-order and for the 3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal/22173821#22173821