# Overload of "Contains" in C#

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to check if two lists are equal.

```
var a = ints1.All(ints2.Contains) && ints1.Count == ints2.Count;
```

The only thing I do not understand is how does `ints2.Contains` work. As far as I know, `Contains()` is a method and takes a parameter. As we can see here, `Contains` is not taking any parameter. 
Note - `ints1` and `ints2` are two different lists.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal/22173821) stackoverflow answer

Comment: You should at least switch the order because the `Count` check is much cheaper

Comment: By the way, your query doesn't take into account how often the ints are contained. So the first list could contain `1,2,1` and the second `1,2,2` and both are considered equal. It also ignores the order. If you want strict equal you can use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: What's important to note here is that *`All`* is a [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function). If you're not familiar with that concept, I could easily see the source for confusion. And I don't think that that aspect is talked of in the linked dupe nor the single current answer here.

Comment: Interesting that you would consider `ints1 = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1 }` equal to `ints2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }` :)

Comment: If the lists are sorted, you can use `SequenceEqual` to compare elements and count, otherwise you can use `GroupBy` as well to sort them on the fly for comparison: `var areEqual = ints1.OrderBy(i => i).SequenceEqual(ints2.OrderBy(i => i));`

Comment: @LiquidCore - I have followed the link you provided and I got the above expression in my question from the link itself but nowhere it explains my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's called a method group. It's basically a shorcut for this:

```
ints1.All(x => ints2.Contains(x))
```