# Object.Contains when object is known to be a collection

Tags: c#

I have a value I'm getting dynamically. This is because it exists in an abstraction method I'm using to build a query from a dot-notation representation of deeply related property.

I need to know if the value contains a particular value. This is easy enough for a string, but when the object in question is a collection I can't figure how to check. I can assume it's a List in my situation, but I don't know what type of list, so I can't achieve a property casting with something like `List<int>`.

So where `x` is an `object` and `spec` is `dynamic` this is how I test for string:

```
return x.ToString()?.Contains(spec, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ?? false;
```

This successfully determines if it's a collection type, but I still can't call `Contains` on it:

```
if (x.GetType().Namespace == "System.Collections.Generic")
{
    return x.Contains(spec); //does not work
}
```

Also tried:

```
var list = (List<dynamic>)x;
var list = (List<object>)x;
```

But this fails in my test scenario with `List<int>`

Comment: You might want to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal

Comment: _I need to know if the value contains another value._ What does it mean? Do you wanna know what property/field is contained or any value in a propery/field?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire updated. Basically `List.Contains()` functionality on an anonymous object.

Comment: @RandyHall convert the object to json string all-inclusive. Then, use string's contains method, which I would do.

Comment: What you're trying to do seems very obscure and I think the question would benefit from a more complete and real example. Other than that, since you're basically duck-typing anyway with little regard to code sanity, why don't you just look for a `Contains` method via reflection and just invoke that?

Comment: Definitely you can do `dynamic list = x;`, although I don't recommend it.