# How to rebuild the indices of a FIFO PriorityQueue memory-efficiently

Tags: c#, optimization, .net-6.0, priority-queue, memory-efficient

Working with the [`PriorityQueue<TElement, TPriority>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.priorityqueue-2) collection, frequently I have the need to preserve the insertion order of elements with the same priority (FIFO order), and AFAIK the only way to do it is by coupling the `TPriority` with an extra incremented `int` index: `PriorityQueue<TElement, (TPriority, int)>`. This works well, but it makes me feel uncomfortable knowing that eventually, if the queue is used for an extensive amount of time, the `int` indices will wrap around the `Int32.MaxValue` limit, breaking the FIFO functionality. I can patch this problem by switching from the `int` to a `long`, making it practically impossible for the index to wrap, but still feels dirty. I wonder if it's possible to do better, by rebuilding the indices of the `TElement`+`TPriority` pairs when the index is about to wrap with the next `Enqueue` operation. So I wrote this extension method for indexed FIFO priority queues:

```
public static void Reindex<TElement, TPriority>(
    this PriorityQueue<TElement, (TPriority, int)> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    (TElement, (TPriority, int))[] entries = source.UnorderedItems
        .OrderBy(e => e.Priority, source.Comparer)
        .ToArray();
    source.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
        source.Enqueue(entries[i].Item1, (entries[i].Item2.Item1, i));
}
```

My problem with this implementation is that it allocates a disproportional amount of memory during the re-indexing. For example 61,456 bytes are allocated for rebuilding the indices of a `PriorityQueue<object, (char, int)>` with 1,000 elements:

```
PriorityQueue<object, (char, int)> queue = new(Comparer<(char, int)>.Create((x, y) =>
{
    int result = x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
    if (result == 0) result = x.Item2.CompareTo(y.Item2);
    return result;
}));

Random random = new(0);
for (int i = 0; i < 100_000; i++)
{
    char key = (char)random.Next(65, 91);
    queue.Enqueue(new object(), (key, i));
}
while (queue.Count > 1_000) queue.Dequeue();

long mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
queue.Reindex();
long mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
Console.WriteLine($"Count: {queue.Count:#,0}, Allocated: {mem1 - mem0:#,0} bytes");
```

Output:

```
Count: 1,000, Allocated: 61,456 bytes
```

[Live demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kXFb3w).

I would like to ask if it's possible to rebuild the indices with zero allocations (in-place), or at least with no more than `System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.SizeOf<(TElement, TPriority)>() * queue.Count` allocated bytes (16,000 bytes in the above example).

Comment: Most implementations do just use the ever-incrementing "timestamp" as part of the priority calculation, as per your code. You might find [this discussion](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/593/is-there-a-stable-heap) interesting.

Comment: @MatthewWatson thanks for the interesting [link](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/593/is-there-a-stable-heap). Regarding the statement that most implementations just use an ever-incrementing timestamp, I would say that, assuming it's true, most implementations are broken!

Comment: You mean broken because the timestamp will wrap around eventually? Yeah, I guess they use `long` like you did.

Comment: That sounds like a pretty strict definition of "broken". There are ~3x as many positive `long` values as it would take to represent every "Tick" from now until the year 9999, and on my machine it consistently takes at least a tick to put an item into a PriorityQueue. I'd say you're fine just using a `long`, and if that "feels dirty" then you can detect an overflow and only re-index when that (never) happens.

Comment: @MatthewWatson assuming an extreme frequency of 1,000,000,000 `Enqueue` operations per second, it would take almost 300 years to wrap a `long` value, which makes it practically safe. But in order to get this statistical safety you have to increase the per element state by 4 bytes, which is not ideal. And this question transcends practicality. It's about ideals! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my tests the biggest memory consumer was the LINQ with ordering (with or without materialization), so just copying the values into array and sorting with `Array.Sort` in-place reduced the memory consumption drastically:

```
public static void ReindexNew<TElement, TPriority>(this PriorityQueue<TElement, (TPriority, int)> source)
{
    ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    (TElement, (TPriority, int))[] entries = new (TElement, (TPriority, int))[source.UnorderedItems.Count];
    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in source.UnorderedItems)
    {
        entries[counter++] = item;
    }
    // hope got comparisons right
    Array.Sort(entries, (left, right) => source.Comparer.Compare(left.Item2, right.Item2)); 
    source.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
    {
        entries[i].Item2.Item2 = i;
    }
    source.EnqueueRange(entries);

    // or something like this, requires time benchmarking 
    // for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
    // {
    //     source.Enqueue(entries[i].Item1, (entries[i].Item2.Item1, i));
    // }
}
```

And "tests":

```cs
void Test()
{
    long mem0 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    queue.ReindexNew();
    long mem1 = GC.GetTotalAllocatedBytes(true);
    Console.WriteLine($"Count: {queue.Count:#,0}, Allocated: {mem1 - mem0:#,0} bytes");
}

Test(); // Count: 1,000, Allocated: 16,136 bytes
Test(); // Count: 1,000, Allocated: 16,112 bytes
```

Comment: This is also a great answer! I think you could optimize the line `entries[i] = (entries[i].Item1, (entries[i].Item2.Item1, i));` with `entries[i].Item2.Item2 = i;`. Value-tuples are mutable.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Updated! Was thinking about that but originally went with "safe" approach and then forgot to check it out.

Comment: I am accepting this answer, although [Jeb's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75941471/11178549) answer is also meeting the requirements, because this one is more performant.

Answer (score 2):

I was just playing around with this puzzle. I'm not an expert. Actually i never used a PriorityQueue. But the **TryDequeue** would reduce the allocations somewhere around 16k bytes

> Count: 1.000, Allocated: 16.152 bytes

because it allocates only one item at a time. I can not say anything about the performance thought.

```
 public static void Reindex2<TElement, TPriority>(
                this PriorityQueue<TElement, (TPriority, int)> source)
            {
                ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(source);
    
                int count = source.Count;
                var orderedItems = new (TElement, (TPriority, int))[count];
    
                int i = 0;
                while (source.TryDequeue(out var item, out var priority))
                {
                    orderedItems[i] = (item, (priority.Item1, priority.Item2));
                    i++;
                }
    
                Array.Sort(orderedItems, (a, b) 
                    => source.Comparer.Compare(a.Item2, b.Item2));
    
                for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    source.Enqueue(orderedItems[i].Item1, (orderedItems[i].Item2.Item1, i));
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks! This looks like a pretty good solution to this problem!