# Difference between a HashSet in C# and HashSet in Java. Any alternatives

Tags: c#, hashset

I came across this strange behaviour in C# vs Java. The HashSet in Java seems to compare the contents in an object and reject duplicates or gives out a boolean value for when it is checked for *contains*. The same isn't true in C#. Here are the code examples:

Java code:

```java
HashSet<List<Integer>> setOfLists = new HashSet<List<Integer>>();

List<Integer> list1 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
List<Integer> list2 = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);

// Adding list1 and list2 to the HashSet
setOfLists.add(list1);
setOfLists.add(list2);

// Checking if list1 is in the HashSet
System.out.println(setOfLists.contains(list1)); // Output is true

// Checking if new Array with same content is in the HashSet
System.out.println(setOfLists.contains(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))); // Output is true

// Checking the length of the HashSet
System.out.println(setOfLists.size()); // Output is 1
```

C# Code:

```cs
HashSet<List<int>> setOfLists = new HashSet<List<int>>();

List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// Adding list1 and list2 to the HashSet
setOfLists.Add(list1);
setOfLists.Add(list2);

// Checking if list1 is in the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Contains(list1)); // Output is true

// Checking if new Array with same content is in the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Contains(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 })); // Output is false
// Checking the length of the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Count); // Output is 2
```

I don't understand why this difference. As we can see in the Print statements, C# is unable to find the duplicates by the contents in case of objects. HashSets are supposed to be used to eliminate duplicates and do so in O(1) time.

The biggest difference I see from the previous answers are all the solutions suggested have time complexity of O(N) where N is the number of elements (lists) in the HashSet. However, in Java, this seems to happen without having to explicitly modifying the comparers, and with O(1) complexity for at least fairly smaller Lists.

Is there any alternate options to achieve that in C# to achieve this in O(1) time complexity?

Comment: The problem seems to lie not in the `HashSet` but the `List` instances. These are not equal (neither using `==` nor using `.Equals`), and have different hash codes. You can try to use the `HashSet` constructor that takes an `IEqualityComparer`, then provide a custom implementation that considers `List` instances equal if their contents are equal.

Comment: @RobSpoor I tried, and I wasn't able to achieve the required with O(1) time complexity. But in Java, this seems to happen without explicity modifying the comparers, and with O(1) complexity for atleast fairly smaller Lists.

Comment: not sure why you expect Java and C# to behave the same... there are certainly much more differences, for example like `Arrays.asList()` returning a fixed-size list (backed by the given array), while `new List<int> {}` is probably¹ returning a non-fixed-size list ( ¹ I do not develop in C#)

Comment: @user85421 Just making my point, why I expect Java and C# to behave the same. Engineer across the Globe who develop in Java and not in C# assume that it behaves the same. In the interviews, if I code in C# and the interviewer doesn't code in C#, he is more likely to assume that I don't know what I am doing, rather than acknowledging Microsoft did not provide this functionality. HashSets and HashMaps are pretty much in every coding interviews, and the interviewers allow candidates to code in the language of their choice assuming this base cases that every language has similar functionalities.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-8.0) class in C# does not overwrite the `Equals()` or `GetHashCode()` method, see [Check if two lists are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22173762/check-if-two-lists-are-equal). This means that the two lists

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
```

are not equal (according to `Equals()`), see the following example code:

```
List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

Console.WriteLine(list1);
Console.WriteLine(list2);

Console.WriteLine(list1.GetHashCode());
Console.WriteLine(list2.GetHashCode());

Console.WriteLine(list1.Equals(list2));
```

This could generate the following output:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]
37320431
339559
False
```

Therefore, the `HashSet<List<int>>` instance contain two list references, which are (still) not equal, as seen in your code:

```
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Count); // Output is 2
```

The solution is to provide a custom [IEqualityComparer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-8.0) implementation the `HashSet` instance should use. It could look like this:

```
public class ListIntSequenceEqualComparator : IEqualityComparer<List<int>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<int> x, List<int> y)
    {
        return x.SequenceEqual(y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode([DisallowNull] List<int> obj)
    {
        return obj.Sum(); // or some other valid hashcode calculation
    }
}
```

With this implementation you get the expected result as in java:

```
HashSet<List<int>> setOfLists = new HashSet<List<int>>(new ListIntSequenceEqualComparator());

List<int> list1 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
List<int> list2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };

// Adding list1 and list2 to the HashSet
setOfLists.Add(list1);
setOfLists.Add(list2);

// Checking if list1 is in the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Contains(list1));

// Checking if new Array with same content is in the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Contains(new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 }));
// Checking the length of the HashSet
Console.WriteLine(setOfLists.Count);
```

This will generate the following output:

```
True
True
1
```